# Regex assistance

Tags: regex

```
Note To Self; This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
Note To Self ; This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
Note To Self : This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
Note To Self: This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
Note To Self - This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
Note To Self- This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
Note To Self This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
NTS ; This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
NTS; This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
NTS : This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
NTS: This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
NTS- This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
NTS - This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
NTS This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS
This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS #NTS
```

Above is the text I am using to test my regex.

I am using this with PHP, and am just trying to extract the string without the prefix.

Essentially, what I am looking for is extracting this string 'This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS' from the given prefixes.

Your help is much appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: by request info was changed.

http://regexr.com?2u3jn

Comment: Why exactly should the two last examples not match? Because `NTS`/`Note to self` is not at the start of the line?

Comment: It was just an example of putting the key phrase inside a string, I only want to extract 'Neither should this even though it contains NTS' from the full string. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I must admit that I am confused. Could you edit your post so we can see exactly how your file should look like after processing? It sounds like this can be done in a single regex. You should also add which regex engine you're using.

Comment: Edited :) - Hope that makes things a little clearer.

Comment: Uh, not really. What does the text look like before and after the transformation?

Comment: Essentially, what I am looking for is extracting this string 'This part of the string should not be changed because it contains note to self and NTS' from the given prefixes.

Comment: So in essence you only want to remove NTS/Note to self (and following whitespace/punctuation characters) if it occurs at the start of a line?

Comment: Yes, and #NTS if it occurs at the end of a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove all instances of `Note to self` or `NTS` if they are at the start of the line, optionally followed by whitespace and/or punctuation, and to remove `#NTS` if it's at the end of a line, you can search for

```
(^(Note to self|NTS)\W*|#NTS$)
```

and replace with nothing.

Explanation in the form of a PHP code snippet:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/(             # Either match...
     ^              #  start of line, followed by...
     (              #   either...
      Note to self  #   Note to self
     |              #   or
      NTS           #   NTS
     )              #  followed by...
     \W*            #  any number of non-alphanumeric characters
    |               # or
     \#NTS          #  match #NTS
     $              #  if it\'s the last thing before the end of the line
    )               # End of the alternation.
    /x', 
    '', $subject);
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing of the RegEx online you can use this: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.
About your RegEx: `()` - group symbols. And within this main group you try to find:

1. `\A(Note to self)`
2. `(NTS)`

The OR here is by `|`

So For selecting all needed just remove the `\A` - bell character (`\x07`) from your search `((Note to self)|(NTS))`.
Reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: `\A` is not the bell character, it's a regex metacharacter (see agent-j's answer)

Comment: Looks like I am wrong, but I am relying only on Second link in my answer. Also for Java and C# this combination is not used..

Answer (score 0):

`\A` is a zero-width assertion that matches the beginning of the string.  You'll want to remove it.

All you need is this:

```
Note to self|NTS
/Note to self|NTS/i                  for PHP (case insensitive)
```

Though if you didn't want to match "RED ANTS", you could do this:

```
\bNote to self\b|\bNTS\b
/\bNote to self\b|\bNTS\b/i          for PHP (case insensitive)
/\bNote to self\b|\b(?<!#)NTS\b/i    also ignores #NTS
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very well for the NTS part, how would I go about making this case insensitive?

Comment: What regex flavor are you using?  C#? Javascript

Comment: It's going to be used with PHP :)

Comment: @Lewis, I added PHP examples... this makes it insensitive `/regex/i`

Comment: (\bNote to self\b|\bNTS\b)\s?[;|:|-]\s seems to work quite well, now I need a way to get the #NTS if it is at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^#?([Nn]ote [Tt]o [Ss]elf|NTS).*
```

Explanation:

- `^` indicates the start of the line (supported in more languages than `\A`)
- `#?` looks for 0 or 1 `#` symbols
- `([Nn]ote [Tt]o [Ss]elf|NTS)` is an or statement, looking for either `[Nn]ote [Tt]o [Ss]elf` or `NTS`.  The `[Nn]` in brackets means to find either `N` or `n` (allowing you to match both "Note To Self" and "note to Self")
- `.*` at the end just matches the rest of the line: `.` is any character, and `*` is any number of repetitions.

Possibly useful references:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html (even if you're not doing Python, I think the examples and explanations are helpful)